# C# Help - FileSystemWatcher Class

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have the following code, although I am trying to output:

```
fileWriter.Write(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name + Environment.NewLine);
```

Although I get the following error:

The name 'e' does not exist in the current context

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileWatcherr
{
class Program
{    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dirPath = "C:\\";
        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dirPath); 
        fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;  
        fileWatcher.Filter = "*.exe";    
        // fileWatcher.Filter = "C:\\$Recycle.Bin";   
        //  fileWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Changed);   
        fileWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Created);    
        //  fileWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Deleted);  
        //  fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);    
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;      

        // updated code
        using(StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test2.txt"))
        {
            var data = true;
            fileWriter.Write(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }



        static void FileWatcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name);
        }

        static void FileWatcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name + " was deleted");
        }

        static void FileWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C:\\" + e.Name);
        }

        static void FileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Name + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's exactly what the error says. You do not have a variable called "e" in the main method.

Comment: @JackMc How can I add the "e" variable to the main method?

Comment: Star Trek flashback; the '[Pakled](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pakled)-to-Programmer' ratio is waaaay to high on this post.  <nasal voice>Make... It... Go...</nasal voice>

Comment: It looks to me that you're new to this. Perhaps you should review the basics about event handling first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` refers to the `EventArgs` parameter of the event methods.

If you put this:

```
using(StreamWriter fileWriter = new StreamWriter("test2.txt"))
    {
        var data = true;
        fileWriter.Write(e.OldName + " was renamed to " + e.Name + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

in the

```
static void FileWatcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
```

method, it should work.

Comment: I have done as so, it copiles ok, but does not output the file :S

Comment: @Michael: Make sure this line in your code is not commented out: fileWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the code, you have the code for the Rename event inside the main method which does not contain a FileSystemEventArgs object (called "e.")

I think to resolve this problem you should change the body of "FileWatcher_Renamed" to the using block.

Comment: Hi, How can I add the FileSystemEventArgs object called e within the main method?

Comment: @Michael The FileSystemEventArgs object is passed to the different events of the FileSystemWatcher class. I edited in a soloution above.

Comment: "I think to resolve this problem you should change the body of "FileWatcher_Renamed" to the using block."